# iptables or proxy to redirect traffic to "slaves" without traffic continuously passing through "main" server?

Tags: proxy, routes, iptables

I have a setup with a "main" server and then a set of "slaves" that do the hard work. All users connect to the "main" that then redirects them to a "slave".

Ideally I want the system to work in such a way that a user connects to "main" who then redirects to a "slave" and then all future communication is done directly between the user and the "slave" without any packets passing through the "main".

Right now I'm using iptables with:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -j DNAT --dport $2 --to $1:$2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -j DNAT --dport $2 --to $1:$2
```

The service is using both UDP and TCP and sessions are established once and then used for a long time with data going both ways (Minecraft servers).

While the setup with iptables works fine, the problem is that (to my best understanding) all traffic passes through the "main" resulting in high data costs. Also, when the slaves look for who they have connected to it seems that they can't even get the ip of the user but rather gets the ip of "main".

How do I make only the "initialization" happen through main and the rest of the traffic to go directly? Do I need a proxy? Should I use some other parameters to iptables?

Thanks for helping! I've been trying to search for the answer but all the terminology in this field makes me confused.

/b3

Comment: Under the belief that it is possible to achieve what I'm trying to do with iptables and/or proxy, I have now built a setup with a dynamic DNS that handles the "load balancing". Of course this limits the flexibility...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like no one will answer this question so I'm gonna give it a try as I've now learnt more.

With IPTables it seems that the traffic will always pass through the main server, and it seems to also be the same with proxies.

Instead, the solution seems to be to set up a Dynamic DNS. I have this running now for some 40-45 servers, but it is causing problems whenever IPs change. Even at a 60 second TTL changes can take several minutes to propagate.